# Do ducted fans have a future in forward flight aircraft? Can they be made more efficient than open rotors?

Tags: aircraft-design, helicopter, propeller, tiltrotor, propeller-aircraft

I'm fascinated by how ducted fans have the ability to be more efficient than open propellers of equal diameter in vertical flight through the use of tight tolerances, lightweight duct material, proper duct lip shape, and other factors. However, when learning that these benefits don't translate over into horizontal flight due to the duct's induced drag and pitching moment, I'm wondering if we'll ever see ducted fans in future aircraft.

I'm aware of the NASA ducted fan manned-aircraft project that failed in the 60's, but today I found out about AgustaWestland's Project Zero and noticed that they tilt the ducts and include fixed wings to provide sufficient lift. How would an aircraft like this compare efficiency-wise to something like a similarly sized  two rotor helicopter?

AgustaWestland Project Zero[image: Photo]

Comment: Isn't this just a ultra high bypass turbofan without the turbo(turbine)?

Comment: @user3528438, not really; there is still a big difference between a short shroud like this and a long duct of a turbofan.

Answer (score 7):

Fan shrouds are a fix for a problem that can normally be designed around in other, more efficient ways. They do reduce tip loses, but usually the tip loses are smaller than the weight and drag penalty of the shroud.

The fundamentals of prop/fan/rotor design is that thrust is proportional to the increased momentum of the air flow, but the power required to get that thrust is proportional to the added kinetic energy i.e. the ''square'' of the speed increase.

Therefore small, highly loaded fans will always be inefficient compared to a traditional helicopter rotor. The fact that they suffer from large tip losses only makes things worse.

So no, we won't see lots more ducts on future aircraft - except for on  jets, which use ducts because the size of their fans are limited by ground clearance and mitigating the losses from shock-waves when the fan blade tips go faster than sound.

Comment: Note that turbofans generally *don't* keep their fan blades subsonic. The tip speed goes up to around M1.5. The real reason for the duct is that the air exchanges speed for pressure in the inlet and flows through the duct at about the same speed independent of speed of the aircraft, so the fixed blades can do adequate work over large speed range. But it requires not just shroud, but duct of some minimal length.

Comment: Would the tip speed be kept subsonic relative to the air around the fan, whose velocity would be significant but subsonic relative to the shroud, or would the tip speed be supersonic within the surrounding air?

Comment: @JanHudec - thanks, I've corrected myself. I saw a good video on supersonic compressor blade tips recently but annoyingly can't find it now!

Comment: @supercat - air in the engine is usually referred to as 'slowed down' relative to the air passing the aircraft (i.e. from the aircraft's point of reference). Of course, from the ground, the air is accelerated. Either way, the fan blades are moving at right angles to the aircraft's motion, and the fan-blade tips are supersonic relative to the rest of the aircraft. What matters is that there are shockwaves inside the compressor.

Comment: @RobinBennett: Would the perpendicular component of the velocity of any part of the blade surface, other than a narrow leading edge, be anywhere close to supersonic, or would the angle of attack near the leading edge be shallow enough, and the curve designed in such a way that the perpendicular component would always be subsonic?

Comment: @supercat - I'm not sure what you're asking. Why do you think the leading edge is moving faster than the rest of the blade? What does angle of attack have to do with speed? The key here is that shockwaves occur when there's a change of pressure in supersonic flow, because that change of pressure can't propagate upstream.

Comment: @RobinBennett: Some portion of the leading edge of any practical blade will be perpendicular to the airflow, but if one could have an infinitely thin  blade and airflow were perfectly laminar and frictionless, a suitably-shaped blade of any size could travel through still air in an axial direction at any speed without disturbing any of the air at all, much less creating a shock wave.

Comment: @supercat - Ah, I see. However the point of a fan blade is to change the pressure of the air around it, so it's at an angle to the airflow, and cambered. Even if there's no stagnation at the front, the low pressure area on the front of the blade, and the high pressure area on the back are moving through the air.

Comment: @RobinBennett: Of course, but the velocity of for every area of the fan blade can be decomposed into a vector component which is perpendicular to its surface and a component which is coplanar with the blade, and in the absence of friction only the perpendicular component would affect the air.  Any portion of the surface whose *perpendicular* component of motion exceeds mach 1 would operate extremely efficiently, but I think spans with super-sonic tip speeds are designed to minimize those areas.